# how would i make this code loop a certain amount of times only using if else statements (no for, do/while,etc.)? (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, random, numbers

Today we have assignment on making random number game. teacher tells tells us we only can use what we learn so far. we did not learn any loop, so i'm stuck using only if/else. how do i use only if/else statement to make random number game loop 8 time and at end of 8 turn it show answer?

i start this code but clueless on how to continue.

```
int main(){
   int Guess;
   cout << "Guess my number!\n\n";
   cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 100. \n";
   cin >> Guess;

   unsigned Number = time(0);
   const int Min = 1, Max = 100;
   srand(Number);
   Number = (rand() % (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
   int tries = 8;

   if (Guess < Number && tries > 0){
      tries -= 1;
      cout << "guess is lower than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
      cin >> Number;
   }
   else if (Guess > Number&& tries>0){
      tries -= 1;
      cout << "guess is higher than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
      cin >> Number;
   }
   else{
      cout << "your answer is right the number is:" << Number << endl;
   }

   if (tries == 0){ 

      cout << "number is: " << Number << endl; 
      system("pause");
      return 0;
   }
   system("pause");
   return 0;

}
```

Comment: You could use `goto`.

Comment: It depends on what you are allowed to use. Can you use `goto`? Can you use functions?

Comment: we have not learned goto. we only learn if/else, switch, rand(),srand(), so i cant use goto.

Comment: You can call the same function it self in a function... which call recursive

Comment: we cannot call function yet. it in chapter 6 of book we are using. we are only in chapter 4 which only deals with if/else and switch nothing further. i was just thinking of copy/paste all if/else statement inside each other, but that only makes code long and unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

if/else are pretty linear, I don't think you really can go back to the beginning using them, maybe your teacher means that you might have to repeat the same lines 8 times, this may seem a bit much but if you made the code a bit more simple it might be pretty straight forward, do you have to have it tell the player if their guess is bigger/smaller, maybe you could just give them 8 tries and get them to guess a number between 1 and 20, I think it isn't good practice to do this without while/for loops, it would make everything more simple if you could just use a loop.

Comment: yeah that was what i was saying but he say it possible to do this way. he also say to use flags or something.

Comment: hmm i dont really know then, i dont know what he means by flags maybe im missing something

Comment: me niether i tried making a flag Fnum = false but does not work anyway i put it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any way to loop back using an `if-else` block. I'm guessing your teacher is giving you this exercise so that you can appreciate loops. Anyway, here's a somewhat neat solution using switch case.

```
int main() {
    int Guess;
    cout << "Guess my number!\n\n";
    cout << "Enter a number between 1 and 100. \n";
    cin >> Guess;

    unsigned Number = time(0);
    const int Min = 1, Max = 100;
    srand(Number);
    Number = (rand() % (Max - Min + 1)) + Min;
    int tries = 8;

    switch (tries) {
        case 8:
            if (Guess == Number) {
                cout << "your answer is right the number is:" << Number << endl;
                break;
            } else if (Guess < Number) {
                cout << "guess is lower than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "guess is higher than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            }
            cin >> Guess;
            tries--;
        case 7:
            if (Guess == Number) {
                cout << "your answer is right the number is:" << Number << endl;
                break;
            } else if (Guess < Number) {
                cout << "guess is lower than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "guess is higher than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            }
            cin >> Guess;
            tries--;
            // repeat code
        case 1:
            if (Guess == Number) {
                cout << "your answer is right the number is:" << Number << endl;
                break;
            } else if (Guess < Number) {
                cout << "guess is lower than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "guess is higher than the number! try again. tries:" << tries << endl;
            }
            cin >> Guess;
            tries--;
        default:
            if (Guess == Number) {
                cout << "your answer is right the number is:" << Number << endl;
            } else {
                cout << "number is: " << Number << endl;
            }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is pretty cool. i never thought of using switch statement like this.

Comment: sorry for doubling comments i spot problem with this though. when ever it move from case to case Number is re-assigned to what ever number typed last. need to change Number to Guess in cin

Comment: It's interesting how the switch is mostly just used for organizing the code, but overall, they seriously need loops to make this not tedious. I sure hope they'll explain the problems with code duplication.

Comment: @user4557924 - Sorry about that. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't really know what you covered in class, I'll just make a list of the options. There are many kinds of "loops":

- `goto` loops, using labels.
- `for` loops
- `while` loops
- `do {} until` loops
- Unrolled loops ( aka. Copy-Paste)
- Recursion

  - You can also use recursion by calling your executable from within the executable
  - You could try calling `main()` from inside `main()` and use arguments, or a global or `static` variable as counter.

Keep in mind there's also the chance that there was something quickly covered in class which you missed, and which isn't in chapters 1-4. You said: Covered in class **or** in the book.

Comment: i am sorry i should made list of what i learn in class 
1)chapter 1: parts of  computer/ how programs work
2)chapter 2: preprocessor directives, variables, cout,cin,data type,constant.
chapter 3: more cin(get,ignore), format, type cast.
chapter 4:relational operators,if, if/else,flags,menus, switch.